# R from command line

Tags: r

I have a question. Here it is guys.

> How do you use R from the command line?

Comment: You're going to need to be a little more specific.

Comment: Indeed, @gung.  Command line within which operating system and/or application, for example?

Comment: Browsing our companion site, Stack Overflow, for technical and programming-related questions about R, I believe you will find a lot of clues for this rather vague question. If this is about running script, try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750786/whats-the-best-way-to-use-r-scripts-on-the-command-line); or more generally, [this query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%2Bcommand+%2Bline&submit=search).

Answer (score 2):

you can call it on a bash shell like this:

```
SHELL$  Rscript my_r_script.R <arguments if any>
```

Comment: There is also [r](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) which was released a few months before `Rscript` started to ship with R itself.

Comment: oh ok ... thanks for the information Dirk. Is there any particular reason for r and Rscript separately ?

Comment: Rscript comes with R, and is released by R Core.  We can't quite reach there with 'r' but it works well on Linux and OS X (and is marginally 'lighter' and 'faster').

Comment: thank you so much Dirk for the information. Its good to know that.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is open R from the command line, then just type the letter $\verb!R!$, but I think you might be asking how to run a script at the command line.

To run an R script, $\verb!example.txt!$ at the command line and write the log to a file, 
$\verb!out.txt!$, type

```
R CMD BATCH example.r out.txt
```

There are a few other options you can pass with the '$\verb!-!$' flag. See

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html

for more information.

Comment: Rscript is clearly superior to 'R CMD BATCH', which predates it.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do pretty much anything you can name in R. The way I gave is a valid one ... I'm not really sure your critique warrants a downvote (this was an answer to the question and it does work) but whatever.